# Trigger Container Registry Vulnerability Scan

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

Is it possible for a person to kick off a scan of a Docker image living in Google Cloud Container Repository? I have an image that's been sitting there for the past weekend and I have yet to see it scanned. I'd like to force it to be scanned, but I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to kick off a scan manually.

If your scans aren't triggered by a push, please verify that the account you are using to push has the "Pub/Sub Publisher" role.

Comment: Are you pushing from a vm? If so you'll need to update your vm scopes to include https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub. You can find instructions at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes